# Static initialization blocks on apple devices

Tags: javascript

I've written some client side JS code that includes a Static initialization block, but for some reason on Iphones/Ipads and some Desktop Macs on both Safari and Chrome (latest versions) don't seem to work and come up with an error:
"Error: Unexpected Token '{'"

I've tracked it down to the static block, as a simple example on the Mozilla site has the same results (just hit the run button in the try it section):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Static_initialization_blocks

On Android phones and tablets using chrome, the problem doesn't show.

Is there something about Apple products that I don't know about that may be causing this and what's the work around here?

Any insight would be helpful.

Many thanks

Comment: It is not compatible with Safari. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Static_initialization_blocks#browser_compatibility

Comment: It is not supported by iOS. https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_classes_static_initialization_blocks

Comment: Thanks Guys, but this is focused on Safari...which is fine, that ticks this one off as explained, but it doesn't seem to work on Chrome on Iphones/Ipads eithe, but works on chrome on an IOS desktop and looking at the charts it implies it should. 
Is there a work around to using this on safari/browsers that cant handle it?

Comment: It works on MacOS because there Chrome uses Blink and V8 as engine to run JavaScript whereas as on iOS it has to use WebKit and JavaScriptCore due to Apple's policies, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

I had that same issue with safari browsers.

According to **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Static_initialization_blocks#browser_compatibility)** and **[caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_classes_static_initialization_blocks)** **the static initialization blocks** are supported in safari browser starting from **2023-03-27**

My solution for my issue was  :
The use of static methods which are supported by all safari versions after **2021-04-26**

```
class myClass {
  static check = false 
  static theCaller = ""
  static  staticMethod(a){
    if ( this.constructor.check ) {

      console.log("already called by " + this.constructor.theCaller)
      return
    } 
    this.constructor.check = true
    this.constructor.theCaller = a
    console.log("loaded")
  }
  constructor(a){
    this.constructor.staticMethod(a)
    
  }
}

a = new myClass("a")
b = new myClass("b")
c = new myClass("c")
```

result in console :

```
loaded 
already called by a
already called by a
```